# How can I calculate the difference between the previous row and the current row when there are blank rows in between, in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to calculate the time between oscillations on a wave, where the time between is the difference between the low point and the high point on any section of the entire wavelength. I have the sheet set up so it tells me if the previous value is lower (wave going up) or higher (wave going down). I want to calculate the time difference between the last-occurring different marker and the current marker. For example, if there is (up, up, up, up, down, up, up, up, down, down, down, down, down, down, down, up, up, up, down) I want to know the time difference between the first 'up' and first 'down' (entry 1 and entry 5), the second change (entry 5 and 8), etc.

How can I calculate the time difference between times when the entry changes?

I cannot figure this out and could not get it to work.

Comment: What do your data look like? Please edit your question.

Comment: Look into MAXIFS and ROW

Answer (score 0):

I would usually accomplish this by assigning an instance number for each thing I am trying to measure, so in this case it would be a wave direction number. Then, use that wave direction number to drive the calculation and identification of when to do some calculation, in this case, the distance from the first up to the first down.

I have data setup in the following way:

Column A: Time Entry
Column B: Wave Direction
Column C: Wave Direction Number
Column D: Wave Length

C2 Formula to identify the wave direction number `=IF(B2=B1,C1,IFERROR(C1+1,1))` which is comparing the current row's wave direction to the previous row's wave direction.

D2 Formula to calculate the change since the first occurrence of the previous wave direction number `=IF(C2<>C1,IFERROR(A2-XLOOKUP(C1,C:C,A:A),0),0)`

The `IFERROR` is just to accommodate the header row.